# How to add metadata to approle entity using vault provider for terraform

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault, vault

I need to add metadata to approle entity because policy path associated with approle is based on entity metadata. What i try to achieve is basically to do this command `vault write identity/entity/id/<entity_id>/ metadata=stage=test`using vault provider for terraform. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation on updating entities](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/secret/identity/entity#update-entity-by-id), you should be able to do this:

```
curl --header "X-Vault-Token: $VAULT_TOKEN"  \
  --request POST  \
  --data "{\"name\": \"<entity name>\", \"metadata\": {\"organization\": \"hashicorp\", \"team\": \"nomad\"}}"  \
  http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/identity/entity/id/:id
```

Make sure to substitute `VAULT_TOKEN` with your Vault token and replace `:id` with the entity id.

Comment: Of course that i can do this from cli or api i want to do the same using terraform and vault provider. This is my issue about.